# couldn't get out of while loop?

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop

I tried the following two scripts. Script 1 got the result I expected. Script 2 didn't - likely stuck in the while loop?

```
$_= "Now we are engaged in a great civil war; we will be testing whether
that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated can long endure. ";

my $count = 0;
while (/we/ig){
    $count++
    };
print $count;
```

Output `2`

```
$_= "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, we will be testing whether
that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated can long endure";

my $count = 0;
while (/we/){
    $count++
    };
print $count;
```

My understanding is `/g` allows a global matching. But I am just curious for script 2,
after Perl finds the first match "we" in `$_` and `$count` now equals to 1, when it loops back, since there is no `/g`, how does it respond? Or does it get stuck exactly because it does NOT know how to respond?

Comment: what a match returns depends on three things: /g or not, list context or not, and whether there are capturing parens (all described in the documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex

```
/we/g
```

in scalar context will iterate over the matches, making the regex an iterator, as it were. The regex

```
/we/
```

will have no iterating quality, but will simply match or not. So if it matches once, it will always match. Hence the infinite loop. Try it out with

```
my $count;
while (/(.*?we)/) {
    print "$1\n";
    exit if $count++ > 100;   # don't spam too much
}
```

If all you want to do is count the matches, you can do something like this:

```
my $count = () = /we/g;
```

Or

```
my @matches = /we/g;
my $count = @matches;
```